# Why local basis of $0$ in topological vector space generates the topology by translation?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

On Rudin there's the following definition:

> A local base of a topological vector space $X$ is thus a collection
> $B$ of neighborhoods of $0$ such that every neighborhood of $0$
> contains a member of $B$.The open sets of $X$ are then precisely those that are
> unions of translates of members of $B$.

But in his book it is only  shown that a set  $E$ is open if and only if each of its translates is open.

Let $U$ be an open set in the topology how do we prove that $U$ is generated by union of translates of $B$?

Comment: If $U$ is empty, it is open. If it is non-empty translate it to the origin, for each $x\in U$ and consider $U-x=\{y-x:\ y\in U\}$. $U-x$ should be open and therefore, contain an element $N\in B$. Then $N+x\ni x$ and is also open and is inside $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ open in $X$. For $x \in U$, $U - x$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$. Therefore, there is an $U_x \in B$ such that $U_x \subseteq U - x$, hence $x + U_x \subseteq U$. Taking the union,
$$ \bigcup_{x \in U} (x + U_x) \subseteq U $$
As $x \in x + U_x$ foreach $x \in U$, we have equality, that is
$$ \bigcup_{x \in U} (x + U_x) = U $$
Therefore $U$ is a union of translates of elements of $B$.